# Validate static dropdown in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have on drop down.

**Model**

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please selectvehicle")]
        public string VehicleRequested { get; set; }
```

index.cshtml

```
   @Html.DropDownList("VehicleRequested", new List<SelectListItem>

                 {
                    new SelectListItem{ Text="Active", Value = "1" },
                    new SelectListItem{ Text="Not-Active", Value = "0" }
                 })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VehicleRequested)
```

I cannot see the required feild validation append, M i wrong any where , please suggst

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dropdownlist only has 2 items, one with `value="0"`, the other with `value="1"` Both `"0"` and `"1"` are valid strings (neither are `null`) so validation always passes. Your property can never be invalid so you never get a validation error.

Its not really clear why your binding a `int` value to `string` property, and the fact you display only 2 values ("Active" and "Not-Active") suggests you property really should be a `bool`.

If you want to add an option such as `"-please select-"` that results in a validation error if one of the other 2 options is not selected, then use the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703561(v=vs.118).aspx) that accepts `optionLabel`

```
@Html.DropDownList("VehicleRequested", new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem{ Text="Active", Value = "1" },
    new SelectListItem{ Text="Not-Active", Value = "0" }
}, "-Please select-")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VehicleRequested)
```

This will add the first option as `<option value>-Please select-</option>`. Note that the `value` attribute does not have a  value, so if its selected when you submit, `VehicleRequested` will be `null` and you will see the error message.

Side note: Suggest you use the strongly typed helper - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.VehicleRequested, ...)` and that you build the your `Selectist` in the controller and pass it to the view as a `ViewBag` or (better) a view model property.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Html.DropDownListFor()`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor((model => model.VehicleRequested, new List<SelectListItem>

             {
                new SelectListItem{ Text="Active", Value = "1" },
                new SelectListItem{ Text="Not-Active", Value = "0" }
             })
```